# Perfmon / PAL: Measurement of send/received bytes for a web server hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net, performance, web-services, iis, perfmon

I have a web server (.aspx pages and WCF interface) hosted in IIS and wanted to analyze the amount of data received/send. The service communicating over the WCF interface was disabled on the client side.
I was creating a Data Collector Set in Perform to track 4h of traffic and analyzed it with PAL. I used the performance counters WebService Total Bytes Received (resp. WebService Total Bytes Send) and expected much more received data, than send. But the send data is much higher.

What exactly is it measuring with the performance counter WebService Total Bytes Received (resp. WebService Total Bytes Send)?

Is the data from/to a WCF service (if it would be requested) also included or is it only my HTTP traffic?

Thanks
Marcel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PAL shows the documentation of WebService.TotalBytesReceived and WebService.TotalBytesSent. It is the data sent and received by the web service. It inlcudes the HTTP and WCF traffic.

As it is not possible to just turn off the WCF service ([How to Start and stop wcf services in IIS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6090bbdc-5009-4c18-9683-2ad8a04ffb64/how-to-start-and-stop-the-wcf-services?forum=wcf)) to just measure the HTTP traffic, wireshark was used to find out how many data will be received/send over the corresponding port.